# What is the equation for an oblique cylinder centered on the origin?

Tags: geometry

I want to find the equations for a solid oblique cylinder centered on the origin.

[image]

What's this equation?

## Work I've Done So Far

Suppose the cylinder has radius $R$ and height $h$.

First, I found the equation for a regular solid cylinder centered on the origin.

$$\begin{align}
x^2 + y^2 &\leq R^2 \\
-\frac{h}{2}\leq z &\leq \frac{h}{2}
\end{align} $$

So then I tried to make a cylinder slanted.

[image]

And looking top down the cylinder moves

[image]

So, then I reasoned that I could just substitute these new values in. My equation for a solid oblique cylinder would be

$$\begin{align}
(x-h\cos(\alpha))^2 + y^2 &\leq R^2 \\
0\leq z &\leq h \sin(\alpha)
\end{align} $$

But this is not centered on the origin. Using my diagram above, the center has $y=0$, and then the average of $(0,0)$ and $(2R + h\cos(\alpha),h\sin(\alpha)$. Then the center is

$$\mathbf{r}_{center}=\left(R + \frac{h}{2}\cos(\alpha),0,\frac{h}{2}\sin(\alpha)\right)$$

So the oblique cylinder centered on the COM is

$$\begin{align}
\left(x-\left(R+\frac{h}{2}\cos(\alpha)\right)\right)^2 + y^2 &\leq R^2 \\
-\frac{h \sin(\alpha)}{2}\leq z &\leq \frac{h \sin(\alpha)}{2}
\end{align} $$

But this also seems wrong to me because I think the $x$ coordinate of the center of a thin cross section of the cylinder should vary with height and my formula has no $z$.

So another possibility might be

$$\begin{align}
\left(x-\left(\frac{z}{2}\cos(\alpha)\right)\right)^2 + y^2 &\leq R^2 \\
-\frac{h \sin(\alpha)}{2}\leq z &\leq \frac{h \sin(\alpha)}{2}
\end{align} $$

This one seems reasonable because (1) the center of the circle would vary with height and (2) it reduces to the regular cylinder when $\alpha = 90^{\circ}$.

Comment: You're drawings are inconsistent. In the first, the edge of the bottom circle is at (0,0,0) and in the second, the center of the bottom circle is at (0,0,0)

Comment: If the slant is in the $x z$ plane, then $$\begin{aligned} (x - z \sin\alpha)^2 + y^2 & \le R^2 \\ \lvert z \rvert &\le \frac{h}{2} \end{aligned}$$perhaps?

Comment: Equation of what - volume? Surface?

Comment: @Moti the equation of the surface and any points contained within the surface

Comment: @None Shouldn't the possible $z$ of the cylinder decrease as the angle gets steeper? Yours doesn't change

Comment: @Tbw thank you! That is why I've been getting an error with a mysteriously appearing $R$

Comment: I assumed you measured the cylinder along the $z$ axis.  If not, then$$ \lvert z \rvert \le \frac{h}{2} \cos\alpha$$.

Comment: If you want the top and bottom to be perpendicular to the axis of the cylinder, then you need to use an elliptic cylinder in rotated coordinates instead.

Comment: My suggestion above is not the correct answer, by the why.  The correct answer should be $$\begin{aligned}(x + z\tan\alpha)^2 + y^2 &\le R^2 \\ \lvert z \rvert &\le \frac{h}{2 \sqrt{1 + (\tan\alpha)^2}}\\ \end{aligned}$$and I'd be happy to explain how and why, if it matches your requirements.  Otherwise, I believe the underlying problem is a matter of *definitions*, not maths per se.

Comment: @None why have you used $\tan(\alpha)$ instead?

Comment: I added my logic as an answer: $\tan$ is used because that's how you define a shear mapping. Consider angles larger than $45°$ to see why.  Also, it turns out that $$\frac{h}{2\sqrt{1+(\tan\alpha)^2}} = \frac{h}{2}\cos(\alpha), \quad -90° \lt \alpha \lt +90°$$though, i.e. my two comments have the same rule for $z$, even though they look different.

Answer (score 4):

### Ordinary Cylinder

An ordinary solid cylinder looks like this:

[image]

An the equations look like this

$$\begin{align}
x^2 + y^2 \leq R^2 \\
|z| \leq \frac{h}{2} 
\end{align}
$$

### Oblique Cylinder

An oblique cylinder looks like this:

[image]

I will show how to derive the equations an oblique cylinder that is sheared in the $xz$ plane.
Importantly, the height of the oblique cylinder should not change because that will change the volume. Therefore, the range of $z$ should remain the same.

A *horizontal shear mapping* is as follows:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x'\\
z'\\
\end{bmatrix} 
=\
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & m \\
0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
z\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x + mz\\
z
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This transformation can be seen using Python:

[image]

Notice the height between the bottom and top remains the same. This is the transformation we want. However, it is not stated in terms of $\alpha$, the angle from the vertical. It's stated in terms of the distance of the top point from the original spot, i.e. $m$ (see the picture above).

Now consider the following:

[image]

In this example, $\alpha_2 > \alpha_1$, so consequently, $cos(\alpha_2) < \cos(\alpha_1)$, which you can see in this side-by-side comparison.

[image]

Call the verticals for each triangle $A_1,A_2$, the horizontals $O_1,O_2$ and the hypotenuses $H_1$ and $H_2$.

Currently, $H_1 = H_2$ but we want $A_1 = A_2$. So we should normalize the adjacent sides to be the same length. This can be done as follows:

$$\begin{align}
A^2 + O^2 & = H^2 \\
\frac{A^2}{A^2} + \frac{O^2}{A^2} &= \frac{H^2}{A^2} \\
1 + \tan^2(\alpha) & = \sec^2(\alpha)
\end{align}
$$
which is the common trig identity. So if we set $m = \tan(\alpha)$, we end up getting this instead

[image]

Notice the heights are now the same, which means for different angles the height will be constant as desired. Thus, the transformation should be

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x'\\
z'\\
\end{bmatrix} 
=\
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \tan(\alpha) \\
0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
z\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x + z\tan(\alpha)\\
z
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So, the equation of the cylinder would be

$$\begin{align}
(x-z\tan(\alpha))^2 + y^2 \leq R^2 \\
|z| \leq \frac{h}{2} 
\end{align}
$$

This is the set of formulas Math Lover provided, so they were correct. However, I found their intuition for why $\tan$ was used lacking so I wanted to supplement.

## Using $m=\sin$ vs $m=\tan$

In the comments, there was some discussion of whether $\sin$ or $\tan$ should be used for $m$. In this Python code, you can clearly see that $\sin$ wouldn't make sense.

[image]

See how even though $\alpha = 90^{\circ}$, $\sin(\alpha)$ doesn't stretch the cylinder waaaay out like we would expect.

However, notice for $\tan$, even at $\alpha = 85^\circ$, the stretch becomes very pronounced

[image]

Also, notice how the norm of the vertical sides for the $\tan$ output become enormous, which is also what you would expect, but it does not for the $\sin$ output.

This can also be seen in 3D here.

With $\sin$ at $\alpha = 90^\circ$,

[image]

Notice, this is the maximum possible slant and we can easily imagine a substantially more slanted cylinder.

With $\tan$ at $\alpha = 85^\circ$,

[image]

## Why it is $x-z\tan(\alpha)$ not $x+z\tan(\alpha)$

If you use $x+z\tan(\alpha)$, that means the center of the top circle of the cylinder would be $x = -\frac{h}{2}\tan(\alpha)$, which is negative for $0\leq \alpha \leq 90^\circ$.

This would produce
$$\begin{bmatrix}
x'\\
z'\\
\end{bmatrix} 
=\
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -\tan(\alpha) \\
0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
z\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x - z\tan(\alpha)\\
z
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and lead to the following cylinder

[image]

This is what None suggested and, as you can see, the cylinder here would be flipped from the desired cylinder with positive $x$ for positive $z$.

Answer (score 2):

Equation of the right cylinder along z axis is

$x^2 + y^2 \le R^2$

between $-\frac{h}{2}\le z \le \frac{h}{2}$

Now you keep the point of the cylinder at the origin fixed and make it oblique along the x axis keeping both bases parallel to the XY plane,

(i) The x coordinate of the center will shift farther away from z axis as the value of |z| increases
(ii) The y coordinate of the center will remain the same.

The coordinate of the center at z will be $(z.tan\alpha, 0,z)$ where $\alpha$ is the angle between z-axis and axis of the cylinder.

The equation of the cylinder will be $(x-z.tan\alpha)^2 + y^2 \le R^2$.

If we want the oblique cylinder to have the same volume, $-\frac{h}{2}\le z \le \frac{h}{2}$ remains the same.

**EDIT:**

added pictures of initial position and oblique cylinder slanted towards x-axis.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where do you get the equation for the coordinates of the center?

Comment: Added pictures. I hope it clarifies.

Answer (score 2):

A right circular cylinder of radius $R$ and height $h$ centered at origin with cylinder axis on the $z$ axis fulfills
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
x^2 + y^2 &\le R^2 \\
\lvert z \rvert &\le \frac{h}{2} \\
\end{aligned} \right . \tag{1}\label{None1}$$

If we want to apply a [shear mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping) to the $x z$ plane that slants the $x$ axis by angle $\varphi$ ($-90° \lt \varphi \lt +90°$), we perform a change in variables
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
x^\prime &= x + z \tan\varphi \\
y^\prime &= y \\
z^\prime &= z \\
\end{aligned} \right . \tag{2}\label{None2}$$

If we have a line segment between $(0, 0, -s)$ and $(0, 0, +s)$ in the original coordinate system, with $0 \lt s \in \mathbb{R}$, the shear mapping would move its endpoints to $(-s \tan\varphi, 0, -s)$ and $(s \tan\varphi, 0, s)$, respectively.  Therefore, its length would change from $2 s$ to $2\sqrt{(s \tan \varphi)^2 + s^2}$.

For the line segment to have a stretched length $h$, we need to solve
$$h = 2 \sqrt{(s \tan\varphi)^2 + s^2} = 2 s \sqrt{1 + (\tan\varphi)^2} \tag{3a}\label{None3a}$$
for $s$.  This is simple:
$$s = \frac{h}{2 \sqrt{1 + (\tan\varphi)^2}} \tag{3b}\label{None3b}$$
However, because
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + (\tan\varphi)^2}} = \cos\varphi \quad \text{ for} \quad -90° \lt \varphi \lt +90°$$
$\eqref{None3b}$ is actually equivalent to
$$s = \frac{h}{2}\cos(\varphi) \tag{4}\label{None4}$$

Therefore, the equation for an oblique (shear-mapped) cylinder with $x$ axis sheared by angle $\varphi$ on the $xz$ plane, height along cylinder axis $h$, centered at origin, is
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
(x - z \tan\varphi)^2 + y^2 &\le R^2 \\
\lvert z \rvert &\le \frac{h}{2} \cos\varphi \\
\end{aligned} \right. \tag{5}\label{None5}$$

Comment: If $x' = x + z\tan(\varphi)$, shouldn't the circle centered on that new point be $(x-z\tan(\varphi))^2 + y^2 \leq R^2$?

Comment: Also, I want the transformation to be volume preserving, so I think the height should remain the same or else the volume would change. Thus, I think the bounds on $z$ should not change or this wouldn't be satisfied. I was mistaken when I suggested they should before.

Comment: @StanShunpike: Yes, that's a typo. Will fix.  Why didn't you mention volume preserving in the first place? You only talked about height. Hrrumph. (It's okay, though; oftentimes finding the correct answer is mostly a matter of finding the right question to ask! :) )

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

A particle is moving on an inclined axis of an oblique cylinder at speed V which has components $(x,z)$ axes as $$ ( V t\sin \alpha,V t \cos \alpha) ;$$

The horizontal cross section always remains the same starting circle centered at origin in its standard form parametrized as

$$ (x= R \cos u, y=R \sin u, x^2+y^2= R^2~)$$

but displaced/modified through above components:

[image]

Drawn for unit speed the oblique axis makes $30^{\circ}$ to vertical  z direction.

Answer (score 1):

The equation of the original upright cylinder is

$ r^T Q r = r_0^2 $

where

$r = [x, y, z]^T $ and

$Q = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 0 \end{bmatrix}$

and $r_0$ is the radius of the cylinder.

Now all you have to do is apply a sheer transformation to the points on this cylinder by an angle $\alpha$ measured from $z$ axis, and pointing in the positive $x$ axis, the sheer transformation matrix is given by:

$S = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && \tan \alpha \\ 0 && 1 && 0  \\ 0 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

So that the image of $r $ is $r' = S r$, from which we can write $r = S^{-1} r'$

Substitute this into the equation of the upright cylinder, and remove the primes from the variable names ($r'$ to $ r$) you get

$ r^T S^{-T} Q S^{-1} r = r_0^2 $

And this is the equation of the oblique cylinder.

Comment: what if the cylinder is tilted along y axis as well? how that will fit into the equation?